# COUNTIF fails to calculate correctly on a filtered list when using a spill formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using `COUNTIF` to compare an array to another array to calculate frequency. The intention is to create a spill array that lists frequency of events. My formula works properly, but when I try to filter on another column, the formula returns `#VALUE!` errors.

Here is a simplified example:
[image: Example of Error]

Me and you are recording who wins games in a table, with the winner in column `Winner` and the game played in column `Game`. You want to see who won the most, so you create a spill formula to calculate frequency (tags 'me' and 'you' are manually added):

```
=LET(
    KeyColumn, Table1[Winner],
    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(KeyColumn)),

    Frequency, COUNTIF(KeyColumn,"="&Categories),
    Frequency
)
```

I see that you won more, but I'm a nerd so sports don't count. I made a table with a column called `Not Sports` and filtered the list using this formula:

```
=LET(
    KeyColumn, Table1[Winner],
    FilterColumn,Table1[Game],
    FilterList, Table2[Not Sports],
    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(KeyColumn)),

    BoolFilterColumn, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn,FilterList)),
    FilteredKeyColumn, FILTER(KeyColumn,BoolFilterColumn),

    Frequency, COUNTIF(FilteredKeyColumn,"="&Categories),
    Frequency
)
```

I get an array the length of `FilteredKeyColumn` with `#VALUE!` errors.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Note: This is just a part of a formula I am making and I actually do need the frequency array as shown.

Edit: Data for reference

Table1

| Winner | Game |
| --- | --- |
| me | tictactoe |
| me | football |
| me | chess |
| me | tictactoe |
| me | chess |
| you | soccer |
| you | football |
| you | tictactoe |
| you | soccer |
| you | football |
| you | chess |
| you | tictactoe |

Table2

| Not Sports |
| --- |
| tictactoe |
| chess |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the countifs and transpose the list of Not sports then use mmult to make it a 1d array:

```
=LET(
    KeyColumn, Table1[Winner],
    FilterColumn,Table1[Game],
    FilterList, Table2[Not Sports],
    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(KeyColumn)),
    Frequency, MMULT(COUNTIFS(FilterColumn,TRANSPOSE(FilterList),KeyColumn,Categories),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FilterList),,1,0)),
    Frequency
)
```

[image]

---

Also by adding CHOOSE we can put the list of winners in the same formula:

[image]

```
=LET(
    KeyColumn, Table1[Winner],
    FilterColumn,Table1[Game],
    FilterList, Table2[Not Sports],
    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(KeyColumn)),
    Frequency, MMULT(COUNTIFS(FilterColumn,TRANSPOSE(FilterList),KeyColumn,Categories),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FilterList),,1,0)),
    CHOOSE({1,2},Categories,Frequency)
)
```

---

A note as to why the error, you are passing an array to COUNTIFS where it will only accept a range.  That is why the error.

Comment: This works well for me. In my actual equation, I need to use multiple filters. I ditched `COUNTIFS` in favor of boolean operations because I couldn't see how to extend `COUNTIFS` in this situation. I posted my formula as another answer. Please give me some pointers if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Craner's answer works well. In my actual usage, I need to extend this to multiple filter criteria. Here is a formula inspired by Scott:

```
=LET(
    KeyColumn, Table1[Winner],
    FilterColumn1,Table1[Game],
    FilterList1, Table2[Not Sports],

    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(KeyColumn)),
    Bool2DKey, TRANSPOSE(KeyColumn)=Categories,
    Mask1, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn1,FilterList1))),
    Bool2DMasked, Bool2DKey*Mask1,
    OnesArray, SEQUENCE(ROWS(KeyColumn),1,1,0),

    Frequency, MMULT(Bool2DMasked,OnesArray),
    Frequency
)
```

It creates an array `Bool2DKey` that is `Categories` tall by the height of `Table1`, filled with booleans indicating a category match in that column (table row).

`Bool2DKey` is further filtered by a boolean mask of the filter, in this case `Mask1`. This can be extended to more filters.

Like in Scott's example, I created an array (called `OnesArray`) to use in `MMULT` to sum the rows of `Bool2DKey`. Using the boolean array and `MMULT` negates the need for `COUNTIFS`.

Here is an extended example where I added more filters:
[image]

The formula is:

```
=LET(
    KeyColumn, Table1[Winner],
    FilterColumn1,Table1[Game],
    FilterColumn2,Table1[Rules],
    FilterColumn3,Table1[Color],
    FilterList1, Table2[Not Sports],
    FilterList2, Table3[Rules],
    FilterList3, Table4[Color],

    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(KeyColumn)),
    Bool2DKey, TRANSPOSE(KeyColumn)=Categories,
    Mask1, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn1,FilterList1))),
    Mask2, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn2,FilterList2))),
    Mask3,TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn3,FilterList3))),
    Bool2DMasked, Bool2DKey*Mask1*Mask2*Mask3,
    OnesArray, SEQUENCE(ROWS(KeyColumn),1,1,0),

    Frequency, MMULT(Bool2DMasked,OnesArray),
    Frequency
)
```

If you want to sum a column (assuming a column of values called `Table1[Count]`), the formula is:

```
=LET(
    KeyColumn, Table1[Winner],
    SumColumn,Table1[Count],
    FilterColumn1,Table1[Game],
    FilterColumn2,Table1[Rules],
    FilterColumn3,Table1[Color],
    FilterList1, Table2[Not Sports],
    FilterList2, Table3[Rules],
    FilterList3, Table4[Color],

    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(KeyColumn)),
    Bool2DKey, TRANSPOSE(KeyColumn)=Categories,
    Mask1, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn1,FilterList1))),
    Mask2, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn2,FilterList2))),
    Mask3,TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(FilterColumn3,FilterList3))),
    Bool2DMasked, Bool2DKey*Mask1*Mask2*Mask3,
    Value2DMasked, Bool2DMasked*TRANSPOSE(SumColumn),
    OnesArray, SEQUENCE(ROWS(KeyColumn),1,1,0),

    Sum, MMULT(Value2DMasked,OnesArray),
    Sum
)
```

Comment: If there are non-numeric values in your sum column, use `Value2DMasked, IFERROR(Bool2DMasked*TRANSPOSE(SumColumn),0),`